# Why has WIndows 7 suddenly restricted access to jEdit?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I went to start up jEdit today and I was shown a message box saying that "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

Trying to run the program as administrator doesn't work. I even changed the permissions to anyone can do anything. Everyone has full control over the exe (at least I believe I did. User shows up twice now, once with full controls, and once with read and write access).

Any idea why this would suddenly happen, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: you'd try to uninstall and install again

Comment: I did that a couple of days ago but it's now happening again.